# Why don't events fire?

Tags: solidity

I have the following contract code:

```
contract ShippingOrder{
    address public oOrigin;
    address public oShipper;
    address public oCarrier;
    address public oReceiver;
    mapping (address => uint) public obalances;
    event Bal (uint balance);
    function ShippingOrder() {
        obalances[tx.origin] = 200;
    }
    function getBalance(address sender) returns(uint) {
        Bal(obalances[sender]);
        return obalances[sender];
    }
```

the getBalance function runs and returns a balance, but the Bal event never emits...

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work perfectly and the event got fired.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific... I don't see the emitted events when I run truffle test. I seem to recall that the emitted events used to display in truffle.

Comment: so edit your question and add more elements in order to help you

Answer (score 1):

From your comment I guess that you're asking about Truffle specifically. Currently Truffle tests only show events in the output log if a test fails. Therefore you could add an `assert.isTrue(false);` inside any `it`-block in which you call a smart contract function that raises event and you'll see the event in the output log.

Comment: It doesn't always work.  It's truly bizarre about when it works and when it doesn't.  In fact it normally doesn't.  Also doesn't work when using `--show-events`.